# How do I send data from my frontend written in React to my backend written in Python?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ['POST'])
def postME():
    data = request.get_json()
    #data = jsonify(data)
    print(data.json())
    return data
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
    
function App(){
    
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const updateSearch = e => {
        setQuery(e.target.value);
        //console.log(query);
    }
        
    const [atID, setAtID] = useState('vangyachibhaji');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(query);
    }, [atID])
    
    const searchID = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setAtID(query);
        console.log("query: " + query);
        setQuery('');
        postToPython();
    }
    const postToPython = () => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/receiver", 
            {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
            // Strigify the payload into JSON:
            body:JSON.stringify(query)}).then(res=>{
                    if(res.ok){
                        return res.json()
                    }else{
                        alert("something is wrong")
                    }
                }).then(jsonResponse=>{
                    
                    // Log the response data in the console
                    console.log(jsonResponse)
                } 
                ).catch((err) => console.error(err));
                
               } 
        
    
        return(
            <div className='Search-bar'>
                <form className = 'search-form' onSubmit={searchID}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='search' onChange={updateSearch}/>
                    <button >search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

I want to send data from a search bar in my webpage (written in React JS) to my python code. The data will be a single simple string, which will be sent to my python code and will be treated as the input.
I tried doing it using Flask but I keep getting an Error 405 (Method Not Allowed). Can someone pls help me out I have been racking my brain for the past 2 days (the stuff after app.run(debug = True) is my React code (.js)

Comment: Please add your code attempt so we can better understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Method not allowed means you have not setup the flask app and the route you are trying to access correctly. Share the code snippets so that we can understand the current status.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LorenzoBonetti I've added the code snippets, pls check it out, thanks

Comment: same goes for @fatalcoder524